# Column spell checking VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need to check all data in column for spellings and abbreviation.

Here's my code:

```
Sub ColorMispelledCells()
    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Not Application.CheckSpelling(Word:=cl.Text) Then _
          cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Anyway I can alter this to make it a column based checking and not cell and not hightlight the cell but instead add a note to the next column that the word is wrong spelling or abbreviated?

Comment: What is your trigger? Directly after enter something or when a button is pressed (or something similar)

Comment: When a button is pressed that's the trigger

Comment: What do you mean "add a note to the next column"? Writing *something* in `cl.Offset(Columns:=1)`? It's not clear what you're looking for, and BTW that `If...Then` statement is dangerously misleading - write multiline `If` statements in `If...End If` blocks, and inline conditionals on a single line. A line continuation and block-indent here is *begging* for bugs to be introduced later.

Comment: You're iterating every cell in `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`. Have you even *tried* seeing what the VBA editor gives you for options after `ActiveSheet.` (upon typing that dot)? Your question reads like you want us to do your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would change the loop to a for loop to go through a single column.  You would need to do more specifics for what the message should be, if it's spelling, abbreviated, etc.

```
Dim i as Long, j as Long, LR as Long
j = 1 'Setting this up for Column A, aka Column 1
LR = Cells( Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row 'Assumes contiguous column j
For i = 1 to LR
    If Application.CheckSpelling(word:=Cells(i,j).Value)=False Then
        Cells(i,j+1).Value = "SpellCheck Error!"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, change your routine that is works with any Range.

```
Sub ColorMispelledCells(r As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r
        if VarType(c.value2) = vbString then
            If Not Application.CheckSpelling(c.Value2) Then
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
            Else
                c.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Variant, not coloring but write a text in the cell to the right - but note that this will overwrite whatever content is in that cell.

```
c.Offset(0, 1) = "You have misspelled something..."
```

Then, add a sub for the button - this will spell check all cells in use (but note that this may take quite some time.

```
sub ButtonPressed()
    ColorMispelledCells(activesheet.usedRange)
end sub
```